# My Tkinter filedialog is not working with my input and my if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, input

When I run my program the if statement and the print work fine, but the filedialog is the only thing that does not work? I found out that my input is my problem, if I remove the input and change download to True instead of a input, the filedialog works fine. This might my ide or python problem, but I think it is just a code problem, and is there any alternative to my code, that might work?

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog
tk = Tk()
tk.withdraw()
download = input("Would you like to download the file?").lower()
if download == "yes":
    print("Choose where you would like to download it:")
    directory = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(directory)
```

Comment: what do you mean by _filedialog is the only thing that does not work_? also can't reproduce the issue, worked completely fine for me (Windows 8.1, Python 3.8.2), also what exactly do you input? do `print(repr(download))` before the `if statement` and tell us what it printed

Comment: My filedialog is the only thing in my code that does not work. It may be because I am on python 3.9.5, why don't you just put the code in your ide, when you run the code it is supposed to open a select file window, try removing the input and change download to true, and if download == yes to if download, then you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @SrikarAnumolu Still works Python 3.9.5 Ubuntu 21... What happens on your computer? Does the popup appear? Is there an error? Is the wrong directory printed out? Also you are selecting a directory not a file

Comment: when using `input` right after that do `print(repr(download))` and tell us what it printed, like what did you input? it works fine for me, there isn't even any visible issues as to why it wouldn't show the window for choosing the directory especially because it works if you simply call the `filedialog.askdirectory()` as you said so the issue must be with your input, so show us what you inputed

Comment: Here: this is the what happens: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SvIG9vKnTed0XK-hjmPgsUi7ttlLEWp_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SrikarAnumolu Try `Alt-Tab`ing to the window (to check if it spawned bellow the editor) but it looks like your editor doesn't like `tkinter`. All of your `tkinter` code is perfectly fine and should work on all OSs and all python3.x versions.

Comment: Also I see that you are using window 11, and it hasn't been released yet. Don't know about the changes there but it is possible that `tkinter` doesn't like Windows 11. If the bugs are caused by that, you can wait until the 5th of October when bugs get filed.

Comment: As @TheLizzard said, the file dialog is open behind the IDLE shell when I tested your code in IDLE.  As the IDLE shell is shown in full screen, it hides the file dialog.

Comment: ohh ok thx ill close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to close my ide and the dialog was there, so it was actually working. Thanks to everyone for helping!